# Remove the first single number from a string

Tags: ios, regex, nspredicate

I need a way to remove the first single number in a string, if it exists. This number must be followed by a space in order to be removed.

Examples:
"3 8 GB memory card" should be converted to: "8 GB memory card"
"8GB memory card" should stay the same.

Please advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex to search:

```
^(\D*)\d+\s+
```

And replace it by empty string.

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pX6uC4/1)

This regex matches:

- `^` - start input
- `\D*` - 0 or more non digits
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `\s+` - 1 or more spaces

---

In **Objective C** use this regex:

```
"^([^0-9]*)[0-9]+ +"
```

Comment: You should also explain how the regular expression works, so someone who is not that familiar with regex would understand it

Comment: I would have used `\b` but OP wrote: **This number must be followed by a space in order to be removed**

Comment: Well isn't the \b covering this ?

Comment: No `\b` will also match `3-8 GB memory card` which is not what OP wrote.

Comment: I am using the string suggested as is in Objective C and it does not match. Could it be the syntax should be a little different in iOS?